# Countdown timer Nan error coming out on safari

Tags: javascript

Good Day.

I currently have a countdown timer running on my WordPress site. The timer represents 2 buying windows and auto rotates to the next buying window. We got the countdown working properly and rotating as it should displaying the proper countdown in Google Chrome but is returning a NaN error on safari.

Not sure what needs to be changed so it comes out working on all browsers. Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks in advance for you time helping me out with this matter

```
var date = new Date();
var d1 = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Toronto"});
var d = new Date(d1);
var n = d.getDay();
var countDownDate = 0;

if ( n < 5 && n > 0) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - n);
    countDownDate = new Date(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1 ) + "-" + (d.getDate()  ) + " 23:59:59").getTime();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
//  jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear());
    jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate()); 
    jQuery(".nmonth").html( d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));    
    jQuery(".nday").html(d.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long' }));
    document.getElementById('sun').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('wed').style.display = 'none';
} else {
    if ( n != 0) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7 - n);
    }
    countDownDate = new Date(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() +1) + "-" + (d.getDate()  ) + " 23:59:59").getTime();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
    //jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear());
    jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate()); 
    jQuery(".nmonth").html( d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));    
    jQuery(".nday").html(d.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'long' })); 
    document.getElementById('sun').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('wed').style.display = 'flex';
}



// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get today's date and time
  var d2 = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Toronto"});
  var now = new Date(d2).getTime();
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="timeline"
document.getElementById("timeline").innerHTML = '<table style="justify-content: right;"><tr class="ctime"><td class="tcenter">' + days 
    + '</td><td> : </td><td class="tcenter">' + hours + '</td><td> : </td><td class="tcenter">'
    + minutes + '</td><td> : </td><td class="tcenter">' + seconds + '</td></tr><tr class="day"><td>DAYS</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>' 
    + 'HOURS</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>' + 'MINUTES</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>' + 'SECONDS</td></tr></table>';


        
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if ( distance < 1) {
      
    //clearInterval(x);
    //document.getElementById("timeline").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    var date = new Date();
    var d1 = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Toronto"});
    var d = new Date(d1);
    var n = d.getDay();
    if ( n < 5 && n > 0) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - n);
        //jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate() - 1);   
        //jQuery(".nmonth").html( d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));
        countDownDate = new Date(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1 ) + "-" + (d.getDate()) + " 23:59:59").getTime();
        //document.getElementById('wed').style.display = 'flex';
        //document.getElementById('sun').style.display = 'none';

    } 
      else {
        if ( n != 0) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7 - n);
        }
        //jQuery(".ndate").html(d.getDate() - 1);   
        //jQuery(".nmonth").html( d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }));
        countDownDate = new Date(d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1 ) + "-" + (d.getDate()) + " 23:59:59").getTime();
        //document.getElementById('wed').style.display = 'none';
        //document.getElementById('sun').style.display = 'flex';
    }
    setInterval(1000);
  }


    
}, 1000);
```